# JoltSpec transform JSON

Tags: json, jolt

I'm quite new to using Jolt for transforming JSONs and I got stuck at this point.
I have an initial JSON which is coming from Kafka and I want to transform it using JoltSpec in order to get the desired final JSON.

**Initial JSON**:

```json
{
  "delta": {
    "base_price": 10094,
    "base_price_with_vat": 12819.38,
    "sale_price": 10094,
    "sale_price_with_vat": 12819.38
  },
  "microtime": 1695024729.857733,
  "offer_id": 83466561,
  "platform_id": 3,
  "vendor_id": 54619,
  "occurred_on": {
    "date": "2023-09-18 10:12:09.857738",
    "timezone_type": 3,
    "timezone": "Europe/Budapest"
  }
}
```

**My JoltSpec**:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "delta": {
        "*": {
          "@(1,&)": "delta\\.&"
        }
      },
      "microtime": "microtime",
      "offer_id": "offer_id",
      "platform_id": "platform_id",
      "vendor_id": "vendor_id",
      "occurred_on": {
        "*": {
          "@(1,&)": "occurred_on\\.&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "delta*": "=toString"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "offer_id": "offer_id",
      "microtime": "microtime",
      "platform_id": "platform_id",
      "vendor_id": "vendor_id",
      "delta.*": "&(0,1)",
      "occurred_on.*": "&(0,1)"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "offer_id": "offer_id",
      "platform_id": "platform_id",
      "microtime": "microtime",
      "date": "occurred_on_date",
      "vendor_id": "vendor_id",
      "timezone_type": "timezone_type",
      "timezone": "timezone",
      "*": {
        "$": "&1.column_name",
        "@": "&1.column_value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "offer_id": "offer_id",
      "platform_id": "platform_id",
      "microtime": "microtime",
      "vendor_id": "vendor_id",
      "occurred_on_date": "occurred_on_date",
      "timezone_type": "timezone_type",
      "timezone": "timezone",
      "*": {
        "@": "records.[]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "records": {
        "*": {
          "column_name": "column_name",
          "column_value": "column_value"
        }
      },
      "platform_id": "platform_id",
      "vendor_id": "vendor_id",
      "offer_id": "offer_id",
      "occurred_on_date": "occurred_on_date",
      "timezone_type": "timezone_type",
      "timezone": "timezone"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "column_name": "ONE",
      "column_value": "ONE"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "platform_id": "=toString",
      "country_id": "=toString",
      "timezone_type": "=toString",
      "vendor_id": "=toString",
      "offer_id": "=toString"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "column_name": "column_name",
      "column_value": "column_value",
      "platform_id": "platform_id",
      "country_id": "country_id",
      "timezone_type": "timezone_type",
      "timezone": "timezone",
      "occurred_on_date": "occurred_on_date",
      "vendor_id": "vendor_id",
      "offer_id": "offer_id"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "kafka_offset": "${kafka.offset}",
      "unique_id": "${uuid}",
      "insert_datetime": "${now():format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')}",
      "insert_date": "${now():format('yyyy-MM-dd')}"
    }
  }
]
```

**Output from above spec:**

```json
{
  "column_name" : "base_price",
  "column_value" : "10094",
  "platform_id" : "3",
  "timezone_type" : "3",
  "timezone" : "Europe/Budapest",
  "occurred_on_date" : "2023-09-18 10:12:09.857738",
  "vendor_id" : "54619",
  "offer_id" : "83466561",
  "kafka_offset" : "${kafka.offset}",
  "unique_id" : "${uuid}",
  "insert_datetime" : "${now():format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')}",
  "insert_date" : "${now():format('yyyy-MM-dd')}"
}
```

But with the mention that I will somehow need to have 4 different JSONs where **column_name** and **column_value** need to take all the values from the initial JSON (*base_price* and *10094*, *base_price_with_vat* and *12819.38*, *sale_price* and *10094*, *sale_price_with_vat* and *12819.38*).

I hope I explained clearly enough to make myself understand what I need.

Best regards,
Andrei

Comment: You should mention the expected output JSON from the above JSON.

Comment: Are you using Jolt within **Apache NiFi** ?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, the expected output JSON is the one above with the mention that beside it, I will need 3 more JSONs that have at column_name and column_value the other values from the initial JSON.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, yes, I have a entire flow in Apache NiFi where there are multiple processors which transform a initial JSON (Flatten, JoltTransform, Split, UpdateRecord, UpdateAttribute etc.) and I am trying to create a single Jolt which covers all this transformations from NiFi in order to use that Jolt in a separate app.

Comment: Well, can you add what JSON output exactly you're looking for as well ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, the JSON output I am looking for is exactly as the one I mentioned above, but I will need 4 JSONs just like it only with column_value and column_name having this columns: 
"base_price": 10094,
    "base_price_with_vat": 12819.38,
    "sale_price": 10094,
    "sale_price_with_vat": 12819.38

Answer (score -1):

Please review the following details to confirm if they align with your expectations.

**Jolt spec:**

```json
[

  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "microtime": "microtime",
      "offer_id": "offer_id",
      "platform_id": "platform_id",
      "vendor_id": "vendor_id",
      "occurred_on": {
        "*": {
          "@(1,&)": "occurred_on\\.&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "delta": {
        "base_price": {
          "@1,base_price": "[#1].column_value",
          "#base_price": "[#1].column_name",
          "@2,platform_id": "[#1].platform_id",
          "@2,occurred_on\\.timezone_type": "[#1].timezone_type",
          "@2,occurred_on\\.timezone": "[#1].timezone",
          "@2,occurred_on\\.date": "[#1].occurred_on_date",
          "@2,offer_id": "[#1].offer_id",
          "@2,vendor_id": "[#1].vendor_id"
        },
        "base_price_with_vat": {
          "@1,base_price_with_vat": "[#2].column_value",
          "#base_price_with_vat": "[#2].column_name",
          "@2,platform_id": "[#2].platform_id",
          "@2,occurred_on\\.timezone_type": "[#2].timezone_type",
          "@2,occurred_on\\.timezone": "[#2].timezone",
          "@2,occurred_on\\.date": "[#2].occurred_on_date",
          "@2,offer_id": "[#2].offer_id",
          "@2,vendor_id": "[#2].vendor_id"
        },
        "sale_price": {
          "@1,sale_price": "[#2].column_value",
          "#sale_price": "[#2].column_name",
          "@2,platform_id": "[#2].platform_id",
          "@2,occurred_on\\.timezone_type": "[#2].timezone_type",
          "@2,occurred_on\\.timezone": "[#2].timezone",
          "@2,occurred_on\\.date": "[#2].occurred_on_date",
          "@2,offer_id": "[#2].offer_id",
          "@2,vendor_id": "[#2].vendor_id"
        },
        "sale_price_with_vat": {
          "@1,sale_price_with_vat": "[#2].column_value",
          "#sale_price_with_vat": "[#2].column_name",
          "@2,platform_id": "[#2].platform_id",
          "@2,occurred_on\\.timezone_type": "[#2].timezone_type",
          "@2,occurred_on\\.timezone": "[#2].timezone",
          "@2,occurred_on\\.date": "[#2].occurred_on_date",
          "@2,offer_id": "[#2].offer_id",
          "@2,vendor_id": "[#2].vendor_id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**output.json**

```json
[ {
  "column_value" : 10094,
  "column_name" : "base_price",
  "platform_id" : 3,
  "timezone_type" : 3,
  "timezone" : "Europe/Budapest",
  "occurred_on_date" : "2023-09-18 10:12:09.857738",
  "offer_id" : 83466561,
  "vendor_id" : 54619
}, {
  "column_value" : 12819.38,
  "column_name" : "base_price_with_vat",
  "platform_id" : 3,
  "timezone_type" : 3,
  "timezone" : "Europe/Budapest",
  "occurred_on_date" : "2023-09-18 10:12:09.857738",
  "offer_id" : 83466561,
  "vendor_id" : 54619
}, {
  "column_value" : 10094,
  "column_name" : "sale_price",
  "platform_id" : 3,
  "timezone_type" : 3,
  "timezone" : "Europe/Budapest",
  "occurred_on_date" : "2023-09-18 10:12:09.857738",
  "offer_id" : 83466561,
  "vendor_id" : 54619
}, {
  "column_value" : 12819.38,
  "column_name" : "sale_price_with_vat",
  "platform_id" : 3,
  "timezone_type" : 3,
  "timezone" : "Europe/Budapest",
  "occurred_on_date" : "2023-09-18 10:12:09.857738",
  "offer_id" : 83466561,
  "vendor_id" : 54619
} ]
```

Comment: what is the expected json? can you clearly mention?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).